# How to Add a Website Background Image to One Page?

Tags: plugins, images, css

What is the easiest way to add a background image to a single page like tryghost.org?

I am currently running under WordPress and was wondering what code I need to add and where. The image is only to be placed on the homepage, and when scrolling down the image should be scrolled down as well. It should also be full width (without destroying image ratio) no matter what the device.

Thanks for the input!

EDIT: Please give a walkthrough on **exactly** what to do for those new to WordPress.

I appreciate everyone's help! *Still Unanswered, will give best answer to Answerer.*

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional Tags: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
Or a custom template for homepage: http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

Then it's a matter of applying a style / class when, for example, `is_front_page()` (or sometimes) `is_home()` (for conditionals), or on your custom template. It's mostly a matter of CSS then.

#### Update/Alternative:

Use Chrome to learn `body` class. Apply style accordingly:

```
body.home {
    background:url(images/home_background.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: More generically, you can use [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) if it's not meant for the Front/Home Page.  For example, if you want it only on the page named "My Special Page", you could use `if ( is_page( 'My Special Page' ) ) { // code goes here }`.

Comment: +1. I like to use `is_page($x)` where `$x` is a specific ID I've already looked up. That way if the slug or page title changes, it will still reference the ID, which is more permanent. Example: `if(is_page(9)) // home page ID { do stuff }`

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input guys. As I am new in WordPress I need some guidance as to what code to put (to set the background image) and where (style.css?).

Comment: Come on man, do a little research. `background:url(image/background.jpg)`

Comment: I like using backstretch.js for fully screen backgrounds. You can wrap the enqueue for the plugin and the initialize timon function in a conditional statement to have it only show up on the page you want.

Comment: Right, so do I put "background:url(image/background.jpg)" in "is_home()" the brackets on the latter? Thanks!

Comment: Nope. Cause that goes in `style.css`. `body.some-kind-of-identifier-slug` probably already exists as a class. Look up what classes Body has on the page you want, and apply a style to it. Use Chrome or Firefox inspector to learn this.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. I want to place the image on my site at magmoz.org. What code do I add and where? Thanks I appreciate your help a lot, even +reped you. :)

Comment: Still in need of an answer!

Comment: So you check and then uncheck this as correct answer? Go do some research dude. You need to do a little work for yourself. You are asking about CSS now, which is off scope of this site. Did you use Chrome to discover the class name being given to the Body tag, as I suggested? If so, then give that a style with your background image. In style.css. The answer is in here if you stop expecting to be spoon fed.

Comment: How do I user chrome dev tools to find the ID? I'm sorry but I can't check it as completed if the issue isn't solved.

Comment: Then don't mark it as completed and change your mind. I can't help you if you don't know how to use a web browser. Or google. See my updated answer anyway. It should work if that page is home page.

Comment: I know how to use Chrome dev tools, just not sure how to change the code you gave me to it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin that let's you do it site wide (if you don't want to jump into code): http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-full-screen-background-image/

If you want per-page backgrounds, then a Pro version is available.